# How to omit na in aggregate to calculate SD in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dat <- structure(list(cohort = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ADC8_AA", class = "factor"), 
    status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, -9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, -9L, 2L, 1L, -9L, 2L), age_onset = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 63, NA, 79, NA, 67, 71, 81, NA, NA, NA, NA, 73, 
    NA, 66, 77, 68, 75, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76, 79, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 70, NA, 77, 84, 78, 76, NA, 92, 64, 60, 72, NA, 81, NA, 
    62, NA, 82, 74)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to get mean and sd like this, but it gets me NA for SD for `status ==-9`. What could be the reason and how do I do this correctly?

```
> aggregate(age_onset~cohort+status, data = dat, mean, na.action = na.omit)
   cohort status age_onset
1 ADC8_AA     -9  82.00000
2 ADC8_AA      2  73.54167
> aggregate(age_onset~cohort+status, data = dat, sd)
   cohort status age_onset
1 ADC8_AA     -9        NA
2 ADC8_AA      2  7.661191
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
aggregate(age_onset~cohort+status, data = dat, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
#    cohort status age_onset
# 1 ADC8_AA     -9        NA
# 2 ADC8_AA      2  7.661191
```

You can use the `...` argument of `aggregate` to pass `na.rm = TRUE` through to `sd`.

You will still get `NA` for any groups that only have a single non-missing value. This is because standard deviation isn't defined for a single value.

```
subset(dat, status == -9)
#     cohort status age_onset
# 23 ADC8_AA     -9        NA
# 46 ADC8_AA     -9        NA
# 49 ADC8_AA     -9        82

sd(82)
# [1] NA
```

Comment: I am still getting NA.

Comment: That's because there is only a single non-missing value. See edits.

Comment: Opps. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(cohort, status) %>%
   summarise(Mean = mean(age_onset, na.rm = TRUE), 
             SD = sd(age_onset, na.rm = TRUE))
```